# com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Unable to upload some APKs?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When I run "./gradlew installDebug" in android project I got the error

```
07:18:34 E/1834104550: Error while uploading app-debug.apk : Unknown failure
Unable to install /Users/yejianfeng/Documents/baichebao/reactclient/android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Unable to upload some APKs
```

and I have devices:

```
➜  android git:(master) ✗ adb devices;
List of devices attached
N7M6R15623003617    device
```

what can i do to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you ever get past this?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error. It was resolved by downgrading `com.android.tools.build:gradle` version from `1.3.1` to `1.2.3` in `build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Visit here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180674
I think it is sdk tools some bug

Answer (score 0):

For me, I noticed I didn't have Intel x86 Atom System Image installed, after I installed  that it worked. (not the Atom_64 one).

Answer (score -3):

A simple way to avoid this problem is the usage of AndroidStudio to open your project.